# French quotes and reference with csquotes and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

I'm trying to configure csquotes so it can manage specific French quotation rules, with the footnote mark placed before the final punctuation mark (yes it's tricky) :

> « This is a complete sentence1. »
>
> « This is an incomplete sentence2».

Following [csquotes' manual](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) (p. 29), here is where I am so far :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\autocite{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#6#4#3#5}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,citestyle=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{fullbiblio.bib} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Some text \textquote[key][.]{quote}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me :

> Some text « quote1. »

And the reference in a footnote.

I still have two issues : how can I add the specific page of the quotation in the footnote (which I can do with autocite `\autocite[32]{key}`), and I don't know why, the footnote quotation style is not `verbose-ibid` with this method, I only have the author and the title.

Comment: I don't have your `fullbiblio.bib` and its `key` entry, but when I use `biblatex-example.bib`'s `sigfridsson` I get a proper full/verbose citation as a I expected. If you don't get a verbose citation I suggest you ask a new question about that (the format of the citation is only tangentially related to the `csquotes` interface) and include the relevant `.bib` entry in the question (or try to reproduce the issue with `biblatex-examples.bib`, which is available on all systems with `biblatex`).

Comment: The thing is that it's not verbose only when called with `\textquote`, it works very well when I use directly `\autocite`. But yes maybe I'll ask a new question, thanks.

Comment: Mhhh, that is extremely odd. As I said, in my test run things looked just fine no matter if I used `\textquote` or `\autocite` directly.

Comment: Ok my bad you are right : I only had author + title because of the way `verbose-ibid`handles ibid.

Comment: Aha! That's one of the reasons we usually want the code examples to be compilable and as self-contained as possible. That way we can be sure that we all see the same thing.

Comment: I know but I wanted to give you a minimal example. It seems it was too minimal!

Comment: My point was rather that it is important that you run your MWE and verify that it shows what you think it shows. Apart from the missing `.bib` entry (which we could substitute with minor difficulty) the MWE was really good. But it didn't show the secondary issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93478/discussion-between-mhr-and-moewe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to give page references in the citation, I would use `\textcquote`, which has a mandatory argument for the cite key and optional arguments for pre- and postnote.

Then you only need to work against `biblatex`'s `autopunct` feature for `autocite=footnote`. This can be done by simply issuing the original definition of `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand` (from [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2232)) again just with the punctuation moving argument `[f]` dropped.

The `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=footnote}` is only necessary in older versions of `biblatex`: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/758. With version 3.12 it should not be needed any more.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=footnote}

\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#6#4#3#5}
\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}
Some text \textcquote[55]{sigfridsson}[.]{This is a complete sentence}
Some text \textcquote[55]{sigfridsson}{This is an incomplete sentence}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Some text « This is a complete sentence1 . » Some text « This is an incomplete sentence2 ».]

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks !

Comment: How would you do the same for \blockcquote ? I tried to add `\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[6]{#1#2#6#4#3#5}` but it blocks compilation.

Comment: @mhr `\mkblockquote` only takes four arguments (it does not need the opening and closing quotation marks): Try `\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{#1#4#2#3}`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!